# Unable to fetch Id in LWC javascript

Tags: javascript, apex, salesforce-lightning, lwc

I created LWC Button and when click on button if record has ParentId the it will fetch the dtails other wise it will not fetch any details.

I am unable to get Id of record in console and

> > > > LWC

```
`import { LightningElement,api, wire,track } from 'lwc';
import updateParentCase from '@salesforce/apex/JSbuttons.updateParentCase'
import {ShowToastEvent} from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
export default class JSbuttons extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId
    @track cases
   
    handleclick()
    {
        console.log('recordid is'+this.recordId)
        updateParentCase({recordId:this.recordId})
        .then((result)=>{
            this.cases=JSON.stringify(result)
            console.log('result is'+JSON.stringify(result))            
            console.log('id is'+JSON.stringify(result)[0].Id)
            console.log('Id is'+this.cases[0].Id)
            if(this.cases[0].Id == null)
            {

                const toastevent2=new ShowToastEvent(
                    {
                        title:'error',
                        message:'This case does not have any parent associated.',
                        variant:'error'
                    }
                )
                this.dispatchEvent(toastevent2)
            
            }
            else
            {
                console.log(this.recordId);
                console.log('result is'+JSON.stringify(result))
            const toastevent1=new ShowToastEvent(
                {
                    title:'Success',
                    message:'Mother Case Updated Successfully.',
                    variant:'success'
                }
                )
                this.dispatchEvent(toastevent1)
            
        }
        })
        .catch((error)=>{
            const toastevent=new ShowToastEvent(
                {
                    title:'error',
                    message:'An Error has Occurred.'+error.message,
                    variant:'error'
                }
            )
            this.dispatchEvent(toastevent)
        })
        
        
    }
}
`
```

> > > Apex class

```
       public class JSbuttons {
       @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Case> updateParentCase(string recordId){
        system.debug('record id is'+recordId);
case updateCase = new Case();
        System.debug('Get the case record Id details'+recordId);
        list<Case> c = [SELECT id,CaseNumber,ParentId,RtlyUptd__c from case  where id =: recordId AND ParentId != null];
        System.debug('Get the case details'+c);
        List<case>  tobeupdatedcases = new List<Case>();
        if(c.size() >0){
            for(case cc : c){
                 
                 updateCase.id = cc.ParentId;
                 updateCase.RtlyUptd__c = 'Feedback Provided';
                tobeupdatedcases.add(updateCase);
             }
        }

        if(tobeupdatedcases.size() > 0){
            system.debug(tobeupdatedcases);
         update tobeupdatedcases;
        }
        return tobeupdatedcases;
}
}
```

I tried to fetch in console by using  **console.log('id is'+JSON.stringify(result)[0].Id)** it is showing undefined but I can able to fetch record result is[{"Id":"5001w00000BNm****D","RtlyUptd__c":"Feedback Provided"}]

Answer (score 0):

In this case your log will always return undefined because you are trying to access an object property of a string.

Notice that first you are stringifying the `result` variable with `JSON.stringify(result)` and *then* you are trying to access the property of the object.

You should just try to access the object property directly without JSON.stringify: `console.log(result[0].Id)`. Or when using JSON.stringify you should include the property within the parenthesis: `console.log(JSON.stringify(result[0].Id))`;

On another note, you shouldn't stringify the result at all before assigning it to `this.cases`.

Your LWC should look something like this:

```
export default class JSbuttons extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId
    @track cases=[];
   
    handleclick()
    {
        console.log('recordid is'+this.recordId)
        updateParentCase({recordId:this.recordId})
        .then((result)=>{
            this.cases=result
            console.log('result is', result)            
            console.log('id is', result[0].Id)

            if(!this.cases[0].Id) // We are assuming that this.cases will always have an object at index 0, what if the array is empty? This should be handled as well.
            {

                const toastevent2=new ShowToastEvent(
                    {
                        title:'error',
                        message:'This case does not have any parent associated.',
                        variant:'error'
                    }
                )
                this.dispatchEvent(toastevent2)
            
            }
            else
            {
            const toastevent1=new ShowToastEvent(
                {
                    title:'Success',
                    message:'Mother Case Updated Successfully.',
                    variant:'success'
                }
                )
                this.dispatchEvent(toastevent1)
            
        }
        })
        .catch((error)=>{
            const toastevent=new ShowToastEvent(
                {
                    title:'error',
                    message:'An Error has Occurred.'+error.message,
                    variant:'error'
                }
            )
            this.dispatchEvent(toastevent)
        })
        
        
    }
}
```